# Uncaught SyntaxError из getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть КРОССДОМЕННЫЙ запрос:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(result){
   //тут пусто!
});
```

Есть ответ со структурой:

```
{"playlist":[
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
]}
```

Есть ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError - Unexpected token ":"
```

Которая ссылается на строку

```
{"playlist":[
```

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Если в переменной result есть объект с указанной структурой, то никакой ошибки быть не может. Но если попытаться выполнить

```
{"playlist":[
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
]}
```

в консоли браузера или вставить этот код в js файл и выполнить, то будет именно та ошибка о которой вы говорите.

Если вы вставляете этот код в консоль браузера или в js файл, то его нужно просто обернуть круглыми скобками

```
( {"playlist":[
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
]} )
```

Все дело в том, что в javascript есть такое понятие как [Блок](http://javascript.ru/Blok), это объединение нескольких команд в блок обозначенный фигурными скобками. Данная синтаксическая контрукция либо никогда, либо очень редко используется в javascript т.к. она не создает отдельной области видимости.

Таким образом, в вашем случае фигурные скобки можно просто сократить и тогда получится такое неправильное выражение

```
"playlist":[
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
    {"comment":"","file":""},
]
```